# How make compiler into android studio project with renderscript?

Tags: android, renderscript

I tried to import multiple android projects with `render scripts`, but often it does not make me `compile` with the "`Project SDK` is not defined" **warning**.

How should I do? Do I have to include some words?

I was interested in this project:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/tests/java_api/LivePreview/

Use `Android Studio 2.3.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sources are part of the platform build, not a normal app build used by Android Studio (or even Eclipse.)  In order to build it in Android Studio, you would need to manually setup your own project structure and pull the code into the correct place.  Sources need to follow the Android Studio / gradle layout (`app/src/main/java/...` for Java sources, `app/src/main/rs` for Renderscript sources, etc.)

The SDK location is typically stored in the `local.properties` file at the top level of your project tree and is developer specific (not committed to rev control.)

Comment: Ok I reported everything in a new project using android.renderscript and not android.support.v8.renderscript, but how should I do to create the scriptC_xxxxx?
I remembered with MakeBuild, but what opens does not work.
Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are asking. The `scriptC` class get autogenerated based on the RS file(s).